# Dart argument syntax - explanation needed

Tags: types, dart, syntax, arguments

I accidentally typed something weird and it compiled but caused a type runtime error

```
class BoldText extends Text {
  BoldText(
    String data, {
    textAlign: TextAlign,
  }) : super(
          data,
          textAlign: textAlign,
        );
}
```

*You can kinda guess what language I come from.*

But what is this part supposed to mean?

```
textAlign: TextAlign
```

IDE hint shows

```
{dynamic textAlign: TextAlign}
```

Which again I fail to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textAlign` parameter is an optional named parameter. You can specify the *default value* of a named parameter as either `= value` or `: value`. The former syntax is now the preferred one, but the latter is still valid.

If you omit the type of any (normal) parameter of a method or constructor, then it defaults to `dynamic`.

So, effectively, the declaration of that parameter is `{ dynamic textAlign = TextAlign }`, which is a named parameter with name `textAlign`, type `dynamic` and default value `TextAlign`.

(The "(normal) parameter" above is there to exclude initializing formal parameters like `MyConstructor(this.myField)` which gets its type from the field it initializes instead of defaulting to `dynamic`).

Comment: Wow, why would we ever need both : and = for default value?

Comment: As @RandalSchwartz says, the `:` syntax was the original syntax for default values of named parameters. It was intended to make named parameters look more like a map literal, where optional positional parameters looked more like a list literal. In practice that similarity was only skin-deep and didn't buy the user anything, so we allowed `=` to be used for named parameters too. We now recommend that you use `=` for both positional and named parameters, but there has not been any urge to remove the old syntax.